How to get coordinates of an arrow?
I was trying to make paintball but have no idea which command to use to get coordinates of the arrow.
I tried `/execute as @e[type=arrow] run fill ~1~1~1 ~-1~-1~-1 concrete replace blue_concrete, but it said that it can't execute command /fill as arrow.
If somebody has idea please share it below.

Hi Roman, what code do you currently have? Have you tried anything yet?

No didn't try anything

I thought I could get coordinates and fill white concrete with colored one

Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.
